# JS game - enemies shoot all their bullets at once (cooldown issue)

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

I've been trying to implement enemies shooting bullets in a pure JS game using only div elements (instead of canvas). But the way I wrote my code they are shooting all their bullets at once instead of shooting one bullet after another.

Problem comes from this for loop I'm using to check if the bullets have reached the fire zone border and should be pushed back in the array to be fired again :

```
for (var b = 0; b < HTMLbullets.length; b++) {
    if (bullets[b].isOut) {
      bullets[b] = {x: turret.x, y: turret.y, isOut: false};
      //bullets[b] = {x: turret.x, y: turret.y +b*50, isOut: false}; //uncomment this line and comment the line above to see each bullet being fired
    }
```

I need to set a cooldown variable to control how much time the enemy must wait before shooting the next bullet, but all I tried so far didn't work.

What would be the best way performance-wise to implement a cooldown between each bullet, knowing that there will be more than one enemy shooting bullets at the same time ?

Demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/Hal_9100/v40ta112/1/

Comment: You could have each bullet keep track of a timestamp of when it was last fired, and compare that to the current time to make sure a certain period has elapsed. See [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

Comment: I tried this approach at some point (after giving up on using setTimeout functions) but it only delayed the whole for loop before shooting all the bullets at the same time. Maybe I did it the wrong way, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: So your goal is to have the turret fire at a regular rate? In that case, have the _turret_ keep track of the last time it fired, and compare to the current time each update

Comment: Yes, as long as there are not more than 10 bullets on the screen at the same time (if so my function makes the turret wait for a bullet to reach its maximum range and push it back at the end of the array).

Comment: As you can see the cooldown indeed works but some bullets are stopping on the screen before reaching their maximum range : https://jsfiddle.net/Hal_9100/v40ta112/2/ . This was the reason I didn't keep on trying with this approach, but I may be missing something obvious

Comment: @Hal_9100, your link is broken.